# Passing value from textbox to datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new at programming (*first week on this area*) and need some help from you guys.
I am developing a small pos where in first form I have a datagridview where the data are showed from sql . The datagridview has those columns (B**C, Name, QTY, Price ,Total)**. The user can edit the qty by typing the qty column on selected row.Now I want to make more easier, the user opens the qty form(**second form by clicking the button**), where the form I loaded the user can type the qty number on textbox. My question is now how should I pass the value from textbox (**2nd form**) on datagridview selected row/ qty column (**first form**) . I don't have any code to show to you, cause as I mention above I am new and don't have any experience. Could some help me about this problem.. Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Delegate and event or you can try the below simple using properties.

Parent Form:

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
        cf.ShowDialog();
        Datagridview[PassQuantityColumnIndex, datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value= cf.TotalVaue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Child Form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public int TotalVaue { set; get; }

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(":Enter the quantity ");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                TotalVaue = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
                this.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my question. But what to add in this part of code "PassQuantityColumnIndex" from your code, cause it is not recognized

Comment: Pass datagridview quantity column number

Comment: Thank you my friend